# Trigger to update column value of tableA on update in two other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a simple **user table** in database with following columns:

```
Id int primarykey Identity column
UserName nvarchar 
Points int
```

There is another table **Posts** in database which have many to one relationship with User Table means a user can have multiple post. The columns of Posts table are:

```
 PostId int primaryKey Identity column
 Message nvarchar 
 Post_Id foreign key
```

Now, suppose any user logged in and post something than in database, PostID is auto created and auto incremented and his message is got posted. UserId column is same as id column in user table.

There is third table called **Comment table** which have many to one relationship with user table.The columns in this table are

```
CommentId int primaryKey Identity column
Message nvarchar 
Comment_Id foreign key
```

**Now, I want to write a trigger which increases points value by 10 in user table if there is an increase in no of post in post table and decrease its value by 10 if there is decrement in post table.**
Similar is the situation for comment table too, i.e for every increment in comment, point increment to +5 and with every decrement in comment, -5.

I have seen multiple examples on stack overflow but not got any idea. Moreover, not seen any example to update column value with trigger. Please suggest me how to accomplish this.

Comment: what part you have problem with? create the transaction? create the trigger?

Comment: i dont know how to write trigger for multiple tables and how to update values based on that. @JuanCarlosOropeza